# Como poner un container-fluid que ocupe 100% de la pag

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap, css3

Tengo un problema, quiero colocar que un container-fluid ocupe el 100% de la pagina para asi poder colocar dentro de el un container para colocarlo en el centro.

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-success" style = "height: 1000px"> <!-- Container total de la pagina -->
<div class="container"><!-- Container del formulario -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 bg-warning d-flex justify-content-center">
             <form class="form-inline">
                  <div class="form-group pt-5 bg-danger">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="¡Que desea buscar?">
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Buscar</button>
                  </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Aca el codigo, lo pude "Solucionar" pero como es de esperar al momento de ingresar desde otro dispositivo este no es responsive asi que no logro saber como poder hacerlo, alguna ayuda?, tambien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta con ponerle el 100% de altura al "container-fluid" y a sus "contenedores", en este caso, el elemento html y body:

```css
html,
body,
.container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid bg-success"> <!-- Container total de la pagina -->
<div class="container"><!-- Container del formulario -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 bg-warning d-flex justify-content-center">
             <form class="form-inline">
                  <div class="form-group pt-5 bg-danger">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="¡Que desea buscar?">
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Buscar</button>
                  </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola parece que utilizas bootstrap. mira este Jsfiddle
[Full height](http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/zrBGw/)

quizás sea de ayuda

```css
.fluid-container {
    height:100%;
}

.fill{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:#990000;
    padding:10px;
    color:#efefef;
}
```